# In NestJS, param annotation is not working with controller

Tags: path, controller, nestjs

I am working on a simple project using `NestJS`.

I came here to ask for help because there was a problem while I was working on the project separating the `controller` and the `service`.

I am going to get the `path value` of the `Get` method from the `controller` and hand it over to the `service`.

In this process, the `controller` was set up as follows.

```
import { Controller, Get, Param, Post, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from 'src/app.service.ts'

@Controller('app')
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get(':vendor/art/:artId')
  findOneByVenderAndUid(
    @Param('vender') vender: string,
    @Param('artId') artId: string,
  ) {
    return this.appService.findOneByVenderAndUid(vender, artId);
  }
}
```

In addition, the global pipeline was set in main.ts as follows.

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

However, when I output the path value received from the service to the console, it appeared as undefined and could not be used.

Is there anything wrong with the part that I implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in the `@Param()`. The string passed to the annotation must mat ch the string used in the url. In this case `:vendor` does not match `@Param('vender')`